# VSCode debug not display map values in VARIABLES area when running a golang debugger

Tags: go, vscode-debugger

Let's say this map is `s.S.Data`, it shows that the length of the map is 2, but just displays nothing. When I add expression `s.S` in WATCH area, it displays correctly.
[image: screenshot]

there is the sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Some struct {
    ID   int
    Data map[string]string
    S    *Some
}

func Print(s Some) {
    var t Some
    t = s // Breakpoint
    fmt.Println(t)
    if t.S != nil {
        fmt.Println(t.S)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := Some{
        ID: 2333,
        Data: map[string]string{
            "1": "A",
            "2": "B",
        },
    }
    ss := Some{
        ID: 7777,
        S:  &s,
    }
    Print(ss)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Is there any way to make it display correctly in VARIABLES area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: set `go.delveConfig.dlvLoadConfig.maxVariableRecurse` other than 1.

More detail:

Open preferences and type `delve` and then press `Edit in settings.json`.

(note: if you choose User tab it will be applied to all VSCode projects, otherwise it will only be applied to this project.)

[image]

After that `settings.json` will be opened with empty JSON object. Write down `go.d` and then there should be autocompletion for `go.delveConfig` popping up.[image]

By pressing enter, you'll get a boilerplate setting for `delve`, which is a GoLang debugger used by VSCode. Edit the value of `"maxVariableRecurse"` key other than 1 and then you will be able to see the deeper variables.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code

Comment: You'll notice that this setting as a signficant performance impact. When you set this to 3 the debugger will run your process much slower.